# How to get entity list dynamically in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, lambda

I need to retrieve a dyanmic object list from entity frmework to generate dynamic report. 
`Normally, In EF: db.People.ToList() will return pepole list.`

What I need here is a dynamic way.

i.e, if a user passes 'People' to  the following method, it should return pepole list. If 'Address', then address object list will be returned.

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetReportModelList(string viewName)
    {          

        var reportList = _baseEntities.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(string.Format("Select * from [dbo].{0}", viewName);

        foreach (var report in reportList)
        {
            var test = report.GetType().GetProperty("DimensionCode");
            var test2 = report.GetType().GetProperties();
            //foreach(PropertyInfo prop in report.GetType().GetProperties())
            //{
            //    String value = prop.GetValue(report, null);
            //}
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As above codes, I'm struggling to get values of properties from dynamic object. Any advice, please?

Answer (score 3):

What is **db**? If it derives from **DbContext**, you can make your method generic like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetReports<T>() where T : class
{
   return db.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var personList = GetReports<People>();
```

or:

```
var addressList = GetReports<Address>();
```

Comment: Do you have or are you able to create DbSet objects within you DbContext class for each of the tables you need to query?  What error messages are you getting?   I don't think you can use **dynamic** in this context because EF will treat the type as an object when it tries to evaluate it at runtime.

Comment: It is returning null values now. I thought List<object> can return from DAL layer. Then, I will get property values of each objects.